# Login screen loads twice with React Native stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack-navigator

I am using stack navigator in a react native app. When I fire up the app on first load, the login screen always seems to load/flash twice. Does anyone know the cause of this based on how i have setup my navigator?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// components
import NavBar from '../../components/nav/NavBar';

// screens
import Welcome from '../../components/screens/Welcome';
import Login from '../../components/screens/Authentication';
import Products from '../../components/screens/Products';
import Product from '../../components/screens/Product';
import RequiresAuth from 'app/helpers/requiresAuth';
import SafeAreaView from 'app/helpers/safeAreaView';

const Root = new StackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: new StackNavigator({
      Welcome: {
        screen: SafeAreaView(Welcome),
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
      },
      Login: {
        screen: SafeAreaView(Login),
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
      },
      Products: {
        key: 'Products',
        screen:
        SafeAreaView(RequiresAuth(Products)
        ),
        navigationOptions: {
          header: <StatusBar />
        }
      },
      Product: {
        screen: SafeAreaView(RequiresAuth(Product)),
        navigationOptions: {
          header: <StatusBar />
        }
      }
    })
  },
}, {
  mode: 'modal',
  initialRouteName: 'Main'
});

export default Root;
```

Comment: Check if the parent component is rerendering and causing the navigator to also re-render

Comment: @ThiagoNascimento I have checked the components and don't see anything that would be causing that. I did however add a console log in componentDidMount and it logs out twice. I am still pretty sure it is the navigator causing this, but i don't know where

Comment: @Ris Did you solve this? If yes, could you please share how. Facing a similar problem.